# Could all [paint-code] questions be retagged PaintCode on SO

Tags: support, retag-request

I'm not sure if there's a reason for the hyphens on SO, but the product seems to be called PaintCode. The tag is called [paint-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paint-code), but it doesn't match the product name which. Can we rename the tag to match the product name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tags are always lower-case. Dashes are used to indicate spaces. So PaintCode isn't an option, but [paintcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paintcode) could be if that's a better reflection of the product name.